# Android Correct View Is Not Being Displayed When Condition Is Met

Tags: android, view

I have a few questions that need answering with this but I will state the initial question first and then the other questions that have arisen. My app is a utility/business app for field use. I have 5 tabs. The contact us tab is in question. In this tab I load a activity called About.class this class loads a Linear layout (vertical) with a web view and either one or two buttons (call || email) depending on whether or not the device is a tablet or a phone (the buttons are wrapped in a horizontal linear layout) Of course this is to be determined buy screen size. I do this in the About.class however no matter the results the same xml file is loaded. Here is the About.class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.util.Log;
public class About extends Activity 
{
    WebView mbrowser;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Integer c = (getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK);
        Integer sml = Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL;
        Integer lrg = Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
        Integer nrm = Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL;
        Integer xlrg = Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;

        Boolean is_tab = isTablet(c,lrg);

        Log.w("SMALL: ", sml.toString());
        Log.w("NORMAL: ", nrm.toString());
        Log.w("LARGE: ", lrg.toString());
        Log.w("XLARGE: ", xlrg.toString());
        Log.w("DEVICE_SIZE", c.toString()); 
        Log.w("IS_TABLET: ", is_tab.toString());

        if (is_tab == true)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.contact_tablet);
            mbrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.view_about); 
            mbrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about/about.html", null);
        }
        else if (is_tab == false)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.contact);
            mbrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.view_about); 
            mbrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about/about.html", null);
        }



    }
     public static boolean isTablet(Integer c, Integer lrg) 
        {

            if (c >= lrg)
            {

            return true;
            }
            else
            {

                return false;
            }
         }

}
```

Now it is interesting to note that those logs **do not** render in the log cat!!!So it is possible that the values are not being assigned. However I have posted the same code in my MainActivity class (which brings me to another question; WHY do the logs appear from there?) and they render the following when running on a tablet (Nexus 7):  
SMALL: 1  
NORMAL: 2 
LARGE: 3  
XLARGE: 4  
DEVICE_SIZE 3  
IS_TABLET: true

Now if the values are not being assigned in the About.class how is there a view rendered if the if / if else statements are not being stepped into?

Thanks for any help in advance. I have another question but will go off topic so I will just post another question :)

**STACK TRACE**

```
07-03 07:55:29.283: I/LOADED:(8031): SPLASHSCREEN
07-03 07:55:34.293: I/ACTION:(8031): STARTING MAIN INTENT
07-03 07:55:34.343: W/SMALL:(8031): 1
07-03 07:55:34.343: W/NORMAL:(8031): 2
07-03 07:55:34.343: W/LARGE:(8031): 3
07-03 07:55:34.343: W/XLARGE:(8031): 4
07-03 07:55:34.343: W/DEVICE_SIZE(8031): 3
07-03 07:55:34.343: W/IS_TABLET:(8031): true
07-03 07:55:34.373: I/ORIENTATION:(8031): HOME PORTRAIT: 1
07-03 07:55:34.373: I/LOADED:(8031): TAB HOME SET
07-03 07:55:34.383: I/LOADED:(8031): TAB FB SET
07-03 07:55:34.383: I/LOADED:(8031): TAB TW SET
07-03 07:55:34.393: I/LOADED:(8031): TAB CONTACT SET
07-03 07:55:34.393: I/LOADED:(8031): TAB LOCATIONS SET
07-03 07:55:45.173: I/LibraryLoader(8031): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
07-03 07:55:45.173: I/chromium(8031): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(116)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
07-03 07:55:45.183: I/BrowserStartupController(8031): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
07-03 07:55:45.183: E/AudioManagerAndroid(8031): BLUETOOTH permission is missing!
07-03 07:55:45.253: W/chromium(8031): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(890)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
07-03 07:55:45.263: W/dalvikvm(8031): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41870ba8)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031): Process: com.laserpros.tech_to_go, PID: 8031
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.laserpros.tech_to_go/com.laserpros.tech_to_go.FourthActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2024)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at com.laserpros.tech_to_go.About.onCreate(FourthActivity.java:24)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
07-03 07:55:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8031):     ... 18 more
07-03 07:55:49.743: I/Process(8031): Sending signal. PID: 8031 SIG: 9  <br/>
  <br/>
```

**In code solution:**

```
 setContentView(R.layout.contact); 
    mbrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.view_about); 
    mbrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about/about.html", null);
    if (!is_tab)
    {
        View callBTN = findViewById(R.id.call_btn);
        callBTN.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    View emailBTN = findViewById(R.id.email_btn);
    emailBTN.setOnClickListener(this);
    Log.w("LOADED: ", "CONTACT TAB");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know you can just create a separate layout for a tablet and let Android decide which one to load for you.  It's really good at this.  Just put your tablet layout in a folder called `layouts-sw600dp` and Android will use it automatically for tablets 7" and bigger.  So it will look like this:

```
res
  |-layouts
  |    |-contact.xml
  |
  |-layouts-sw600dp
  |    |-contact.xml
```

Here's some more information about resource targeting.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: unfortunately all of my testing of this approach causes the application to crash when selecting the contact us tab.

Comment: CaseyB's answer is the right way to go. Doesnt explain the problem in your code, but still. 1. what's the stack trace ? that may point you at the original problem. 2. can you see logs from your other activities (i.e. not main) ? 3. if you use breakpoints do you get to About.onCreate() ?

Comment: I do believe CaseyB's answer is correct as thats what the documents say and that is the way that all my drawables and orientation views work.I just don't know why it doesn't load when the layout-sw600dp file is added with the edited contact.xml. to answer your questions. 1.see above 2.i can see logs throughout all my other activities. after you brought up this question I put logs in every activity at various locations to check code stepping. All work except About.class even when this class works without the layout-sw600dp 3. Don't know how to use correctly or how to step from brk pt 2 brk pt

Comment: That stack trace is from LogCat I assume thats what you meant. I check other questions to make sure I had the right info.

Comment: Okay issue is fixed.. Thank you for your direction. This solution was a combination of CaseyB's answer (main solution) and a code adjustment. I needed to render the listener for the call button inert. The view loader was looking to initialize a button that was not in the view so if (!is_tab) then set up call button.

Comment: I also have to apologize.. i didn't add the button wiring in my initial post for some reason.